# IBOutlet of another view controller is nil

Tags: swift, null, iboutlet

I have a storyviewcontroller which has objects on its view. I need to change the text on the UILabel(In the storyviewcontroller) and the load the view on an array. I have connected the IBOutlet to the label in the storyviewcontroller.

```
class StoryViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var inspiredButton: UIButton!
```

I have created an object of the storyviewcontroller class and am able to access its variables. However, after creating the object of the storyviewcontroller, the IBOutlet is nil. Because of this, I get an exception saying found nil while unwrapping

```
let story:StoryViewController = StoryViewController()
story.textLabel.text = sampleText()
```

Can you please help me with this!
Here is a link to the whole project
https://github.com/abhishekagarwal2301/DTC
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IBOutlets are initialized during view loading process and they are not accessible at the point you are trying to reach them. Instead you must declare a string variable to your viewcontroller and set text to label on its viewDidLoad method (after the loading process has finished)

```
class StoryViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var inspiredButton: UIButton!
    var text:String!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    textLabel.text = text
   }
}
```

And from first controller initialize text variable as follow

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
var story = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourVCIdentifier") as StoryViewController
story.text = sampleText()
self.presentViewController(story, animated: false , completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Is it necessary to load the view controller or can i do this in the init function of the class?

Comment: No you don't need the init function since view controller viewDidLoad method is always called automatically.

Comment: If Im not wrong, in obj-c you could just do initwithnibname... That however does not work here. Could you please tell me why. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but I'm not familiar with objective-c as I started iOS development with Swift directly

Comment: Oh, okay! Thanks and Ill try doing what you said

Comment: Ok let me know if its working or if you have any other problem

Comment: The problem still persists. The IBOutlet is nil even inside the viewdidload class StoryViewController: UIViewController {

    IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var inspiredButton: UIButton!
    var labelText:String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textLabel.text = labelText                   textLabel is nil and hence this gives an exception

Comment: The problem is the way how you are trying to initialize your view controller. Check the edited answer

Comment: This is when you want to initialize the view but is not for a initialized view.