# Access to ViewController outlet from TableViewController loaded at same time

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, google-maps-sdk-ios

I was reading the thread: [IBOutlet of another view controller is nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741399/iboutlet-of-another-view-controller-is-nil)

I have a problem very similar to that.

**RequestViewController**

```
class DenunciasResueltasViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!
    var solicitudes = [SolicitudesModel]()
    var tempMap: GMSMapView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 3.4824182, longitude: -8.1776567, zoom: 15)
            self.mapView.camera = camera
    }

func recenterMap(latitude:Float!, longitude:Float!) -> Void {

        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latitude), CLLocationDegrees(longitude))
        mapView = tempMap
        self.mapView.animate(toLocation: coordinates)
    }
```

**RequestTableViewController**

```
class RequestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

//Some code to fill the table


        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RequestVC") as! RequestViewController
        viewController.recenterMap(latitude: solicitudes[indexPath.row].getLatitude(), longitude: solicitudes[indexPath.row].getLongitude() )

        return cell
    }
}
```

Both components are initialized at same time in runtime, I mean, both are part of the same View.

And when the users click in a 'row' I wanna update the `mapView`

for that resason, I'm using the method 'RecenterMap'

But, the variable 'self.mapView' is always 'nil'.
How I can update this value?

Comment: Set a CLCoordinate property to know where to center the map, set it when you create the viewcontroller, and on viewDidLoaf or appear, call `recenterMap()` on that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to do the recentering, because this is called when the user tapps on a cell. It could be that the Outlets of the first viewcontroller haven't yet been set when the second starts to fill its cells.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, wanting to access properties of a currently offscreen vc before you are going to present it.

You can solve it by forcing the view hierarchy to be build by accessing its view:

```
let _ = viewController.view
```

After this you are free to access any view-related property on the viewcontroller. So you should put it before you call `.recenterMap`

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what are you trying to do: your code seem to instantiate a view controller with map for each table cell, but you don't actually present it after being instantiated.

You instantiate the `RequestViewController`, but it doesn't appear in the view hierarchy, thus the `IBOutlet` properties are not instantiated at that moment when you call them. Usually calling a `view` on a `UIViewController` instantiates all the outlets on it. 
Alternatively, you could call `self.present(requestViewController)` in order for it to be presented.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is that, you have both the RequestViewController and RequestTableViewController, both are subview of a parent View,

1- your center on map function needs to be called on the delegate method :

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

2- You need a reference to the RequestViewController and **DO NOT INSTANTIATE IT FROM THE STORYBOARD.** as you will get a new instance and not the one that is displayed already.