# Passing the property of text of a Label from the FirstVC to the SecondVC returns nil

Tags: swift, label

facing a nil exception while passing the property of text of a label on the FirstVC and reflecting it to the SecondVC on a Label aswell.

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

https://github.com/marlhex/PasingDataAroundVC

[image: Debugger Desc.]

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toSecondSegue" {

            // Instance to the next screen
            let svc = segue.destination as! SecondVC

            // Assigning the same value to the next screen
            svc.sameName!.text = self.originalName.text
        }
    }
```

Does anyone knows how to pass the data accordingly?

I know the default value of the property of text of the label will be nil, but I am just stopped by this, I know, incredible

Comment: When reviewing the duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49818897/1226963 for an answer that directly covers your specific issue.

Comment: @rmaddy can we also consider it as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741399/iboutlet-of-another-view-controller-is? In addition, I might mention that `text` could be declared as a *property observer* to edit the value of the label text...

Comment: @AhmadF Yes, that is also a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is nil until the vc loads , so

```
svc.sameName!.text = self.originalName.text
```

so using ! will crash the app , you need to declare a string inside the destination class like

```
@IBOutlet weak var sameName: UILabel!

var str = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sameName.text = str   // assign here
}
```

then assign it in sender vc prepare

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toSecondSegue" {

            // Instance to the next screen
            let svc = segue.destination as! SecondVC

            // Assigning the same value to the next screen 
            svc.str = self.originalName.text
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use delegates?

```
protocol firstVCDelegate {
    func passingName(_ text: String)
}

class FirstVC: UIViewController {
    public weak var delegate: firstVCDelegate?

    func goToSecondVC() {
       self.delegate?.passingName(futureName.text)
    }

}

class SecondVC: UIViewController, firstVCDelegate {

    func passingName(_ text: String) {
      sameName.text = text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass text directly to a `UILabel` that is not loaded into the view when you try to assign the value.

You need to pass `originalName.text` to a `String` `variable` in the SecondVC, and then assign that value to the `UILabel` in `viewDidLoad`:

**SecondVC**

```
var name: String!

@IBOutlet weak var sameName: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sameName.text = name
}
```

**FirstVC**

```
svc.name = self.originalName.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the sub controller instance directly from FirstViewController. You can do this by using the String variable as following.

> Declare temp String variable in SecondViewContorller and set that
>   value to your label controller in viewDidLoad as following.

```
/// Temp string value to set over the controller
var tempValue: String = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.sameName.text = self.tempValue
}
```

**Hope this will solve your issue.**